# Plotting data by year over year using plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a data look like this:-

```
Month    Year       Value
Jan      2015       2.8          
Jan      2015       2.0   
Mar      2016       0.9    
Feb      2015       3.1  
Mar      2016       4.2   
Feb      2015       2.1    
Mar      2016       2.3       
Feb      2015       1.1
Apr      2016       1.3
Apr      2016       0.5
```

Now I want to plot line chart, but by using this code, I am getting this output. below [image]

Code I have used:-

```
df = rslt_bb.sort_values(by='Year')
trace = go.Scatter(
x = df["Year"],
y = df["Value"],
mode='markers+lines'
)

layout = go.Layout(
#title='Distribution by year',
xaxis=dict(title='Year'),
yaxis=dict(title='Value'),
showlegend=True    
)

fig = dict(data=[trace], layout=layout)
offline.iplot(fig)
```

I want the plotting should be like not aggregated all common year in the same line, I want spreaded. All year, single data should be visible separately, like this way below, [image]

Comment: it is not possible with the data you have.

Comment: The plot does what it should. If you have no additional information, e.g. month, it's simply not possible.

Comment: @Simon Fint yes I have month columns.

Comment: Still, you could calculate the average for each year to get a single point to plot. Would look better, that your plot.

Comment: @Simon Fink, can you help me out with the code I have edited the dataset above please help me according to that.

Comment: @Joseph is it possible now? forgotten to add a month.

Comment: @Ram Take a closer look at the dataset you've provided. You have two different values for `Jan 2015`. This is not a continuous dataset. If it were, you could interpolate for missing dates to illustrate it. But right now that will not work.

Comment: @Ram, you also have a day column?

Comment: @Simon Fink, No day column, as per your below code I merged year and month in one column.
 -> 0.0017  2017-04-01
                                   -> 0.0022  2017-04-01
now as you can see there are many dates repeating so can you help me out by calculating means or anything you can suggest. (or by average) so that it can easy to be plottable.

Comment: Then you still have to consider, what @vestland mentioned. Several data points for the same date. For this consider `pandas.groupby` functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph your advice also helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to crate a `datetime` object for plotting a `Time Series`. So instead of

```
x = df["Year"]
```

use

```
# import pandas as pd
x = pd.to_datetime(df.Year*100+df.Month, format='%Y%m')
```

Comment: gkk = rslt_bb[['Date', 'Value']].groupby(['Date'])['Value'].mean().reset_index().sort_values(by='Date')   Thanks @Simon Fink after your above code i write my code and its working fine. Thanks. And I am marking Your answer as answered.